# Deligne-Lusztig and Character sheaves

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, perverse-sheaves, deligne-lusztig-theory

Consider: $G$ - a nice group ($GL_n$) over a finite field $F$. $X$ - the flag variety. Consider a nice $G$-equivariant $l$-adic sheaf $\mathcal{M}$ on $X \times X$, equipped with Weil structure.

Fix $g \in G^F$. We will produce two numbers, and ask whether these are equal.

1) Pull and Push $\mathcal{M}$ along $G \leftarrow G \times X \to X\times X$, where the left arrow is the projection, and the right arrow is identity times action. Call the result $ch(\mathcal{M})$. Our first number is the trace of Frobenius on the fiber of $ch(\mathcal{M})$ at $g$.

2) Pull $\mathcal{M}$ along $X \to X\times X$, which is identity times Frobenius. Now take the trace of $g$ acting on the cohomology with compact supports of the resulting sheaf. It is our second number.

Question: When can we assert that these two numbers are equal? For example, if $\mathcal{M}$ is lower shriek of the constant sheaf on the diagonal, it seems to be true.

Thank you

Comment: If $\mathcal M$ is the constant sheaf on the whole space - the nicest sheaf I know - the first construction gives the trace of Frobenius on $H^i(X, \mathbb Q_\ell)$ and the second construction gives $\chi(X)^2$, which is unrelated.